# Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log n}{n^{2}}$ convergent? How to show that?

Tags: convergence-divergence

Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log n}{n^{2}}$ convergent? How to show that? I was trying to prove Mertens third theorem and i got stuck at this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $\log (n) \le n^{0.5}$ and use the comparison test.

Comment: Was writing exactly the same. You win.

Comment: A general claim can be proved: For all $\alpha , \beta , >0$ it holds that $\frac{\log^\alpha (x)}{x^\beta}\xrightarrow{x \to \infty}0$

Comment: @AmihaiZivan Yes that has always irked me. I mean $\log$ is asymptotically lower than *any* positive power of $x$, and as soon as the power reaches $0$, it goes "lol. nope. i win"

Comment: Yup, it's definitely a nice result which can be proved quite easily.